# Using multivalue output parameter with ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, parameters, multi-values

Can you give an example of how to use a multivalue output parameter with ArcPy?

Answer (score 4):

Bruce Nielsen provided this answer at at a no longer reachable thread on the old [ArcGIS Discussion Forum](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/28771-Python-list-to-MultiValue-output-parameter) and it seems to have been accepted there.

> Since a multivalue input parameter is a text string delimited by
> semicolons, I would think the output parameter would be the same. In
> theory, you should be able to create the appropriate output with the
> following change to the example code:

```
arcpy.SetParameter(3, ';'.join(listOfClippedOutputLayers))
```