# Parsing multivalue parameter using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool

I am trying to get my head around how multivalues derived from the arcpy command `GetParameterAsText` gets looped through a script. Could some please provide a sample script that does the follow basic task so that I may study it for further insight?

Get a set of shapefiles from `arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)` (the number of shapefiles can vary from to 10 say) and then loop through each shapefile, displaying the following with `arcpy.AddMessage` saying something to the effect:

> "This is shapefile " shapefile name

When looped through all of the shapefiles, print the message "No more shapefiles"

Comment: Related: [How do I correctly use 'MultiValue' in Python script parameters?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35553/how-do-i-correctly-use-multivalue-in-python-script-parameters)