# ArcPy merge using a list from GetParameterAsText

Tags: arcpy, merge

I am pretty new to ArcPy so bear with me.  I am having a hard time understanding how to feed a list of FCs from a "GetParameterAsText" into something like the merge tool.  I have my GetParamterAsText window set to Feature Class and multivalue so I can drag a group of layers into it in the tool dialogue.

```
inputLayer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
```

When I run the merge command, it looks like it is messing up the expected syntax by putting ";" as a separator instead of ",".

Doing this:

```
arcpy.Merge_management(inputLayer, outputName, "")
```

Throws me this error:

```
"C:\Development\Merge_Dissolve\GA0combined.shp;C:\Development\Merge_Dissolve\GA25combined.shp" does not exist
```

I have tried to create a function to replace ";" with ",", but it doesn't seem to work on my inputLayer variable, but I'm guessing there's a more standardized way to working with a list of FCs with tools that accept multiple inputs such as Merge.

Comment: please try to form one question. Make it have a question mark at the end. A clear question will likely get an answer quicker than asking for guidance.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35553/how-do-i-correctly-use-multivalue-in-python-script-parameters/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use split to convert parameter to list expected by Merge.

```
inputLayer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

list2merge=inputLayer.split(";")
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how you would use split?

Answer (score 3):

try

```
parameter = arcpy.GetParameter(1)
inputLayers = parameter.values()
```

This should give you the different layers as a list
Afterwards you can access the individual layers by index or in a loop

```
layer = inputLayers[0]
```

or

```
for layer in inputLayers:
   (do something with your layer)
```

Comment: This was very helpful.  Thanks!  I figured out something that is working...now to just fully understand WHY. =)

Comment: @GYS can you elaborate for future reference?

Comment: @GYS don't forget to choose an answer when you get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of successfully formatting values for a tool that accepts multivalues in Python.

1. A semi-colon delimited string of data is a valid input for any geoprocessing parameter that accepts multiple inputs. This is valid, and is what you will be getting from `GetParameterAsText` on a multivalue parameter.
2. A list of strings of the feature classes (or layers, or table views, or whatever the tool parameter accepts).
3. A list of `arcpy.Value` objects. If you use `GetParameter` this is what you should be getting.
4. Create and populate an `arcpy.ValueTable` object. I don't recommend this per se as it's more effort than it's worth, but it will work.

If you've done #1, and it's not working, I would question whether the data does exist.

Answer (score 1):

So the answer was that I needed to create a list and then feed that into the merge command.  I'm not sure why #1 didn't work from @DWynne as that has worked for me in the past (and how I approached this at first) on another tool that takes multiple inputs.

This was my basic flow:

```
inputLayer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
layerList = inputLayer.split(";")
arcpy.Merge_management(layerList, tempmergeName, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I needed to do in order to use a list of feature classes listed in a text file. A little off topic since the OP is specifically asking about GetParameterAsText() and I'm side-stepping the function. It is however directed at the same end goal: feeding Merge_managment a long list of inputs.

```
import arcpy

#inputLayer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
#outputFC = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

inputLayer = r"X:\source\all-footprint-featureclasses.txt"
outputFC = r"X:\work\default.gdb\all_sat_footprints"

ff = open(inputLayer)

# Open text file and put each line into a list element
#   --> ["path1","path2", ...]
layerList = ff.read().split()

print(f"{layerList[0:1]}...")
arcpy.Merge_management(";".join(layerList), outputFC, "")
  # ";".join() turns ["path1","path2"] into --> "path1;path2"
print(arcpy.GetMessages())
```